# Maven compiler plugin fails to find symbol for mixed (java-scala) codebase

Tags: java, scala, maven, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a codebase of java and scala files in the same folder in a project (total 5 files). Couple of java files refer to a class defined by one scala file. I use the scala-maven-plugin (v3.2.2) to compile the sources. When trying to use the latest mvn-compiler-plugin (v3.5.1), even though the scala compiler runs first and compiles all the files (both java and scala), maven-compiler-plugin kicks in later, tries to compile the java files only, and fails with a message: Symbol not found - for the object that is defined in the scala file.

Here is some output.

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ GraphDB ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/xx/GraphDB
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (default-cli) @ GraphDB ---
[INFO] /media/xx/GraphDB/src/main/java:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /home/xx/GraphDB/classes at 1465363494733
[INFO] prepare-compile in 0 s
[INFO] compile in 4 s
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ GraphDB ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ GraphDB ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /home/xx/GraphDB/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /media/xx/GraphDB/src/GraphTest.java:[23,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable TitanGraphProvider
  location: class com.ilabs.dsi.titan.GraphTest
[ERROR] /media/xx/GraphDB/src/AddStatic.java:[229,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable TitanGraphProvider
  location: class com.ilabs.dsi.titan.AddStatic
```

The symbol "TitanGraphProvider" is in a scala file.

I am using the command "mvn clean scala:compile package" for doing this. I have noticed that if I break down the command into "mvn clean scala:compile" and "mvn package", then the first command goes through, but the second fails with the same errors at the same step. Seems like the later java compilation stage is kicked in by the package step.

What is the correct way to achieve mvn package in this type of scenario?

**Edit:** Looks like I did not provide the complete scenario. I was trying to compile the codebase from a shared folder on a Virtualbox VM running Debian, and the underlying file system was Windows (10). When I moved the folder to a non-shared location on the VM, things went fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to compile the codebase from a shared folder on a Virtualbox VM running Debian, and the underlying file system was Windows (10). When I moved the folder to a non-shared location on the VM, things went fine.

However, I did not have any problem in the above setting while compiling a project consisting of all scala files. Not sure what gives, but at least this is a solution for the above problem I was having. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure you have:

```
             <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks. I already had the same plugin, and had the second <execution> block (along with the config block). I added the first <execution> block in my pom and tried again, but that did not seem to help. I got the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. I've fixed it by making sure that Scala sources are compiled before Java. In my case Java code can be considered superseded by Scala and so the dependency is Java -> Scala. Here is how I've configured scala-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.3.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>add-source</goal>
            <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same type of error, and the problem was about compilation order between java and scala files: in the end all are compiled as .class files mixed in the same folder/package hierarchy, however either the java files are all compiled first, then the scala ones (thus java can't see scala code), or the other way around depending on the config (see other answer about such config).

So, same issue as most answers here. But I have another solution: To not choose the order between scala and java, you can put both java and scala files in the scala src folder, i.e. `src/main/scala/`. The scala compiler compiles both and manages dependencies in both direction scala-on-java and java-on-scala. The only trade-off is that java files are found in scala folder, but personally I don't mind.